# PHP Form throwing improper error that all fields must be complete

Tags: php, html, forms, validation

This PHP form was built on a staging website for testing purposes. When the form is filled in on that staging site it correctly sends an email to the myemail. This code has been uploaded onto the prod website and for whatever reason whenever the form is submitted, including when all of the fields are correctly checked for validation, the form refreshes with a validation message stating that all fields are required. On the staging site this issue isn't occuring and the contact emails are sending. On the prod server the error is being thrown and no contact emails are being sent. We aren't sure why this is happening - any clarity would be appreciated. Staging is running 5.3, Prod is 5.4 and on Godaddy. Postmaxsize = 128mb.

**HTML for Form**

```
<!-- Form Section -->
<br>
<div class="section_container_500">
    <form id="contact_form" method="POST" name="contactform" action="contact-form-handler.php"> 
                    <p class="contact_error_text">Oops! All fields are required.</p>

        <p>
        <label for="name">Full Name<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> <br>
        <input class="text_input" type="text" name="name">
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="email">Email Address<span style="color: red;">*</span></label> <br>
        <input class="text_input" type="text" name="email"> 
        <br>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="user">I am a…</label> <br>
        <select class="text_input" name="user">
            <option value="patient">Patient</option>
            <option value="HSP">Health Service Provider</option>
            <option value="investor">Investor</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="phone">Phone Number (Optional)</label> <br>
        <input class="text_input" type="tel" name="phone"> <br>
        </p>
        <p>
        <label for="message">Message<span style="color: red;">*</span>:</label> <br>
        <textarea class="text_input" name="message"></textarea>
        </p>
        <input class="mid_CTA, form_submit" style="display: block; margin: auto;" type="submit" value="Send"><br>
    </form>
</div>
<br><br>
```

**PHP for Form**

```
 <!-- Code for validating the form -->
<script>
    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactform");
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name"); 
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email"); 
    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid email address"); 
</script>

 <?php 
        $errors = '';
        $myemail = 'fake@fakeemail.com';
        if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
           empty($_POST['email']) || 
           empty($_POST['message']))
        {
            $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
        }

        $name = $_POST['name']; 
        $email_address = $_POST['email']; 
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $user = $_POST['user']; 
        $phone = $_POST['phone']; 

        if (!preg_match(
        "/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
        $email_address))
        {
            $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
        }

        if( empty($errors))
        {
            $to = $myemail; 
            $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
            $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
            " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n User Type: $user \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
```

Comment: Could it potentially be a reserved word? I find using variables like 'user', 'email', 'name' can sometimes conflict with other variables. Just a thought. or...Does your $myemail need to be the website url? something@mywebsiteURL.com?

Comment: @ThomasByy I'm not sure - it was working on staging without issue

Comment: So the 'empty($_POST)' checks or the preg_match check is throwing the error?

Comment: @ThomasByy seeing the following errors in console upon form submission: 

1) Uncaught ReferenceError: Validator not defined at contact-try-again.html:41

2) GET <url> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT

Comment: Try disabling your adblocker or using IE.